# Where do you find the password attempts setting or option in ICS?

Tags: security, settings

I want to either stop this function or at the very least set the number of attempts to a higher number than 3.

Comment: What do you mean? The lock screen (which is 5 per 30 second lockout) or the sim pin (3 incorrect and sim is puk locked). Neither can be changed.

Comment: At the lock screen, after a failed attempt I am greeted with the message "You have incorrectly attempted..." Ok, I see, you are saying that there is no way to change that number.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the limit on incorrectly entered screen lock codes, unless you make your own custom ROM with this ability.

It should be set at 5 incorrect entries triggers a 30 second wait period - if this isn't the case then the ROM maker has changed this.

Comment: @Tony If my answer has answered the question, please consider clicking the tick to mark it as the answer!